# What will and will not run on .NET 2?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I have Visual Studio 2012 and have my target framework set to .NET 2.0.

But I have:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(example => Threadedmethod(intval,classVal) );

void Threadedmethod(int id, MyClass val)
{ ....  }
```

and it compiles.

How can I tell if this will work from VS2012? I have been told the `=>` operator is not compatible with .NET 2.0.

Comment: Why do you care about the compiler version? You can still use the latest compiler and the old .NET version.

Comment: as i'm told to use c# 2.0 features only for this project. and i like to know.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding your requirement, or the person giving you the requirement doesn't understand the difference between .NET 2.0 and C# 2.0. They are totally distinct issues.

Comment: is this the same as the above?
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { Threadedmethod(intvalclassVal);} );

Comment: You should really stop being so frightened of telling your client the truth. If necessary, send them to this post and tell them "John Saunders said so". The compiler version does not restrict which .NET Framework version the code can run on. There is no reason you can't use C# 3.0 to C# 5.0 in an application that targets .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confused with `.net` version and `c#` version. When you target to .Net 2.0, you can still use c#(language features) like lambda, extension methods, collection initializer, object initializer etc.

This has nothing to do with the .Net version. Thing is you can't use classes which are newly added in .Net version > your target version.

Keep in mind that when it gets compiled your code is perfectly valid and it will run properly in machine with only .Net framework 2.0.

> I have been told => is not valid in .net 2.0

It is wrong, correct statement would be *is not valid in **c# 2.0*** but you're not using c# 2.0 in VS2012. It is c# 5.0 compiler you use there.

For more information read [Jon's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) especially **Using C# 3 in .NET 2.0 and 3.0** part.

My conclusion: *Your application will work perfectly in .Net 2.0 without any doubt*.

Answer (score 1):

> as I have been told => is not valid in .net 2.0

This is not true. You can run .Net 2.0 framework on VS2012.

Check this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) which lists all the framework which are allowed in VS2012.

> Visual Studio 2012 Dev11 11.0 **2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5**
>   02012-09-12September 12, 2012

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Framework targeting does not guarantee that your application will run
>   correctly. You must test your application to make sure it runs against
>   the targeted version. You cannot target framework versions that are
>   earlier than the .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: so this is saying that in vs2012 I cannot guarantee it will run under .net 2.0?

Comment: No, it's saying that you can use features froom the C# 3.0 compiler while targeting .NET 2.0 and it will run without problem.